# como fazer consultas passando 2 parametros via Curl?

Tags: json, libcurl

Preciso fazer  enviar via curl um usuário e uma senha em txt mesmo, é só para teste, por exemplo

curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json"  http://127.0.0.1/students/

quero passar o usuario e uma senha nessa consulta, alguem pode ajudar

é GET , preciso passar os parametros pois um metodo vai consultar o banco e ver se é valido.

Comment: então e se passar os parametros diretamente no URL: `curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1/students/PARAM1/PARAM2`?

Comment: então mas no metodo eu tenho outros parametros que posso receber, tipo , posso receber 4 parametros, mas irei passar somente 2, como identificar quais desses 4 parametros disponivel etou enviando via curl ?

Comment: Mas isso é um login? Não devia estar a passar via `post` como é imensamente recomendado?

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo como enviar em formato json:

```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"usuario":"foo","senha":"bar"}' http://127.0.0.1/students/
```

`usuario` e `senha` são os nomes dos parâmetros.

`foo` e `bar` são os seus repectivos valores.

Comment: maravilha, mas deixa eu perguntar, se eu mandar via POST ele não irá fazer uma inserção ?

Comment: não necessariamente... o que define o que vai ocorrer é a aplicação e não o método de envio..... um “insert” pode ser feito mesmo com método GET